# Can't refer to a custom user control

Tags: c++, .net, xaml, uwp

I have a custom user control and I want to include it in the main page.
**ColorPalette.xaml.h** (It also includes `xaml` and `xaml.cpp` files, just I didn't post them)

```
namespace Colibry
{
    namespace Views {
        [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
        public ref class ColorPalette sealed
        {
        public:
            ColorPalette();
        };
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Colibry.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Colibry"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:Colibry.Views;assembly:Colibry"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <cc:ColorPalette></cc:ColorPalette>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

But `xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:Colibry.Views;assembly:Colibry"` outputs an error:

> Универсальный код ресурса (URI) "clr-namespace:Colibry.Views;assembly:Colibry" не является допустимым идентификатором пространства имен.  Colibry E:\Projects\Colibry\Colibry\MainPage.xaml

For Englishman:

> URI "clr-namespace:Colibry.Views;assembly:Colibry" is not available identifier of the name space. Colibry E:\Projects\Colibry\Colibry\MainPage.xaml

How to fix it? Just I learn C++/XAML only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WPF/Silverlight/Windows Phone 8** way:

`xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"`

**WinRT/Universal App** way:

`xmlns:controls="using:MyApp.Controls"`

Using one platform's syntax will fail to compile on the other and vice versa. 
There are small difference between "clr-namespace and using".This is discussed in greater detail in these two articles. [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx) and [XAML namespaces and namespace mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping).

Above all,you could change "clr-namespace" to "using" and delete any assembly token and semi-colon (the assembly will be inferred). The result looks like this:

```
  xmlns:cc="using:RefCustomControlTest"
```

I have used the custom usercontrol like the following code and it working pretty well.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <cc:ColorPalette x:Name="test" />
</Grid>
```